# How to align DIV boxes next to each other in a container?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I would like to align my div boxes for a client's website all perfectly next to each other and without some being bigger than others. Here is the page relating to the code: https://www.imaniskinclinic.com/treatments

The boxes are not inline and some are obviously bigger than others. I added a div box container which I thought would hold the boxes more nicely but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Can anyone give me some assistance and guidance on what I must do?

Here is the code: CSS then HTML

```css
.box {
  background-color: white; /* for visualization purposes */
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  
}



div.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #f8abbe;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
 font-family : verdana, arial, helvetica, helve, sans-serif;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
  
<div class="box">
  <div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/acne.htm" >
    <img src="images/acne.jpg" alt="Acne" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Acne Treatments</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/hair%20removal.htm">
    <img src="images/hairremoval.jpg" alt="Hair Removal" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Laser Hair Removal</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/electrolysis.htm">
    <img src="images/electrolysis.jpg" alt="Electrolysis" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Electrolysis</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/thread%20veins.htm">
    <img src="images/threadveins.jpg" alt="Thread Veins" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Thread Veins</div>
</div>
  
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/microderm.htm" >
    <img src="images/microderm.jpg" alt="Microdermabrasion" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Microdermabrasion</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/rosacea.htm" >
    <img src="images/rosacea.jpg" alt="Rosacea" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Rosacea</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/pigmentation.htm" >
    <img src="images/pigmentation.jpg" alt="Pigmentation" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Pigmentation</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/skin%20peels.htm" >
    <img src="images/skinpeels.jpg" alt="Skin Peels" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Skin Peels</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/botox_lipfillers.htm" >
    <img src="images/botox.jpg" alt="Botox/Lipfillers" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Botox & Lipfillers</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/semiperm.htm" >
    <img src="images/microblading.png" alt="Semi Perm" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Eyebrow Microblading & Semi-Permanent Make-up</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/mc.html" >
    <img src="images/mc.jpg" alt="Massage and Cupping" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Massage & Cupping</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any differences in size. Have you tried adding `float: left;` to `div.gallery`?

Comment: @HappyAnt I've just realised it's sort of fixed itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added display: inline-block;
If you play a little bit with sizes of divs it will look better

```css
.box {
  background-color: white; /* for visualization purposes */
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  
}



div.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #f8abbe;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
 font-family : verdana, arial, helvetica, helve, sans-serif;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
  
<div class="box">
  <div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/acne.htm" >
    <img src="images/acne.jpg" alt="Acne" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Acne Treatments</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/hair%20removal.htm">
    <img src="images/hairremoval.jpg" alt="Hair Removal" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Laser Hair Removal</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/electrolysis.htm">
    <img src="images/electrolysis.jpg" alt="Electrolysis" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Electrolysis</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/thread%20veins.htm">
    <img src="images/threadveins.jpg" alt="Thread Veins" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Thread Veins</div>
</div>
  
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/microderm.htm" >
    <img src="images/microderm.jpg" alt="Microdermabrasion" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Microdermabrasion</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/rosacea.htm" >
    <img src="images/rosacea.jpg" alt="Rosacea" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Rosacea</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/pigmentation.htm" >
    <img src="images/pigmentation.jpg" alt="Pigmentation" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Pigmentation</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/skin%20peels.htm" >
    <img src="images/skinpeels.jpg" alt="Skin Peels" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Skin Peels</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/botox_lipfillers.htm" >
    <img src="images/botox.jpg" alt="Botox/Lipfillers" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Botox & Lipfillers</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/semiperm.htm" >
    <img src="images/microblading.png" alt="Semi Perm" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Eyebrow Microblading & Semi-Permanent Make-up</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="aesthetics/mc.html" >
    <img src="images/mc.jpg" alt="Massage and Cupping" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Massage & Cupping</div>
</div>

</div>
```